# Is there a standard format for Dependent QBF?

Tags: lo.logic, sat, boolean-formulas

I know there is a standard input format DIMACS for a formula is in conjunctive normal form (CNF) and QDIMACS for quantified Boolean formulas. Is there a similar standard format for the Dependent-QBF (DQBF)?

Comment: Don't know why people have down-voted this? Stupidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard format proposed. At [QBFEVAL’18](http://www.qbflib.org/qbfeval18.php) there is a DQBF-track, which uses DQDIMACS from a paper by [Föhlich et al](http://forsyte.at/wp-content/uploads/idq_pos2014.pdf.) on IDQ.